# How to Filter a row

Tags: vb.net

I created a view for report. I imported data to the report. In columns null values are also present. If i filter one row using filter in vb.net the null values of row cannot be displayed.

For example, column names are ID, Name, Number, Place. In this some of the places number has null values I include filter ID, Name ,Number,Place. If I filter using ID the null values of number cannot be displayed.

This is the code I tried but not filter

```
IN FORM TextBox1.Text=""

TABLE1BindingSource.Filter = "YOUR FIELDNAME LIKE '" + TextBox1.Text.Equals (String.Empty) + "'")
```

Expected Result

> Table
>
> YOUR FIELDNAME
>
> value1
>
> value2
>
> NULL
>
> value3
>
> NULL
>
> NULL
>
> value4

Answer (score 0):

That filter doesn't make sense.  This part:

```
TextBox1.Text.Equals(String.Empty)
```

is going to evaluate to `Boolean`, i.e. `True` if the `TextBox` is empty and `False` if it's not.  That means that your filter ends up being:

```
YOUR FIELDNAME LIKE 'False'
```

or the like.  What you should actually be doing is something like this:

```
Dim columnName As String
Dim fieldValue As String

'...

TABLE1BindingSource.Filter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}%'", columnName, fieldValue)
```

Note a number of things there.  Firstly, the use of `String.Format` to make this sort of code more readable.  Secondly, the use of the actual value entered by the user and not a `Boolean` indicating whether that value was empty or not.  Thirdly, the use of a wildcard because using `LIKE` without a wildcard makes no sense.

It should also be noted that that code is only going to work with text fields, because they are the only ones that get delimited by single quotes and the only ones that you can use `LIKE` with.  If you want to filter on a numeric field or some other data type then you'll have to write your code to create the filter differently.

Comment: Thanks Mr.jmcilhinney this code is usefull to me and i want to display null values in the list. Your code displays only not null values only

Comment: My code has nothing to do with NULL values at all.  If there are rows that match your filter then they will be displayed, whether they contain NULLs or not.  If what you're saying, without actually saying, is that you want to be able to filter on NULL values then that's different.  You can't use `=` or `LIKE` or any other usual operator for NULLs.  You must use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.  For instance, if you want to filter a column on a certain value and NULLs then you would use something like `SomeColumn IS NULL OR SomeColumn = 'Hello World'`.

Comment: TABLE1BindingSource.Filter = String.Format("'{0}%' LIKE '{1}%'", columnName, fieldValue)

Comment: That makes no sense.  The first value should be a column name so why would it be wrapped in single quotes and combined with a wildcard?

Comment: I have 5 more columns to filter so if will filter i want to return back all data so only